# Return HTML view in .NET Core Console application with Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, console-application, kestrel-http-server

I've got .Net Core Console application. I've been trying for awhile to make it possible to run `Process` and listen to `port` at the same moment and this was my way of doing it:

This is my `program.cs` class:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ConsOut = Console.Out; 
        Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Stream.Null));
        BuildWebHost(args).Start();                    
        Console.SetOut(ConsOut); 
        while (true)
        {
            RunIbit();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseIISIntegration()
           .Build();

        return host;
    }


    public static void RunIbit()
    {
        // Execute Proccess.Start();
    }}
```

and here is `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddLogging();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);

        return WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(ContainerManager.Container, services);
    }
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
        app.Run(context => {
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
        });
     }
}
```

Since I want to show the results of the process in a web page I've been wondering whether it's possible to do that somehow instead of writing that `Hello world`?
Tried adding `app.UseMvc()` instead of `app.Run(context => {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
            });` but it didn't work with .net core console application and this was the only that worked for me (or at least the one I found) but I couldn't find how to replace that text with html file. Does anyone know a way?

Comment: Would having `Process` write an HTML file, then simply use `app.UseStaticFiles()` to serve said HTML file work?

Answer (score 2):

> I've been trying for awhile to make it possible to run Process and listen to port at the same moment

short answer :

1. reference packages as dependencies
2. configure services and add a middleware to serve incoming request
3. use your own controllers and views as your need

here's a how-to in details :

I'm not sure whether you want to achieve the goal via MVC solution or static html files , so I provide you with two solutions :

Plan A : As I notice that you have said

> tried adding app.UseMvc() ... but id didn't work

let's config a console program with MVC first .

Plan B : config a console with static files .

Just as a reminder , either Plan A or Plan B requires a `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK . So we must reference correct SDK at frist , namely change the project sdk from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
   <!-- ... -->
</Project>
```

#### Plan A

1. We need first add package references in your `.csproj` file :

```html
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="appsettings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
      </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

2. and then you can configure MVC in your `Startup` class:

   ```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           // ...

           services.AddMvc();     // add mvc services here

           // ...
       }

       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       {

           app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();   // use mvc  here

           app.Run(context => {
               return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
           });
       }
   ```
3. At last , you can add controllers and views file as you need . For instance , if you add a HelloController with a Index action , and the coresponding  view file is :

   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
   }

   ### Index

   it woooooooooooooooooooorks

you will get a response as expected when you access the URL `/hello`
[tes-console-with-mvc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BQAp.png)

#### Plan B

you can simply add a `wwwroot` directory in your project and register a middleware with `UseStaticFiles()` in `Configure()` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env){
    // ...

    // app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    app.UseStaticFiles();     // add a StaticFiles middleware here

    app.Run(async context => {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello,world");
    });
}
```